# Where should I dispatch actions to fetch my data using React-Native and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I want to fetch all the data needed to display the dashboard of my app in react-native. The app is similar to [the facebook one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnouh.jpg)

I am using react-native, redux, redux-saga, react-navigation and a REST api.

I have to fetch **the post list** to display the main page and **the notification count** for the headerBar. The other tabs pages are mounted at the same time as the main one to allow fluid transition. So I need **the current user** too for the Account page

Finally, the store is persisted and the app can stay in background mode for a long time. So I need to refresh my data often to be sure to have the last changes.

I have sagas which make the call and launch actions to update the store.

Here the strategies I found :

1. I can connect each page component and give them a `fetchAllPageData()` which dispatch a fetch action that I call in `componentDidMount`
2. I can connect smaller components to allow them to pull the data they need with the same strategy (ie. `fetchUser` to the component that display the user in the Account Page, `fetchNotificationCount` to the component that display the number of notifications ...)
3. I can use create a redux-middleware which listen for page change and call all fetch data actions.

I am currently using a mix of the first and second solutions but I am not very happy with it :

- I don't always know where the data are fetched
- The strategies which refresh the data once the component is mounted are a bit "hacky" and random
- I often have the to move where the call is done when refactoring

What is the state of the art on this subject? What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

The usual recommendation is to intercept actions that make AJAX requests in the middleware and resolve them there before passing the result through.

[This article](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/using-middlewares-in-react-redux-apps-f7c9652610c6) explains it in more depth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use redux-saga to do that job. The question is more "Where should I dispatch the action?"

Comment: Is your data real time? If so, maybe Websockets would be more appropirate than AJAX. Otherwise I'd be inclined to listen for page changes and resolve the actions in middleware before rendering the response. It should be easy to set a loading spinner field in the state if necessary.

Comment: This approach is similar to what I do with Angular 1 applications - basically fetch all the dependencies before triggering the transition to another page. That way the user never sees a flash of unstyled content, and you can display a loading spinner as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can / should do in componentDidMount or componentWillMount.